# Require bigquery in Bigquery DataForm script file

Tags: node.js, google-bigquery, google-api-nodejs-client, dataform, google-bigquery-dataform

**Context**

I am using the Dataform-Preview in BigQuery. As it is a node.js project I wanted to work around the constraints Dataform poses regarding retrieving/loading data from BQ-tables to use it for advanced processing.

Thus, I `npm install --save @google-cloud/bigquery` adding it to the `package.json` and also installed it in the web-IDE.

**Error**

I created a `sample.js` file inside the include-directory and required the package as usual.

```js
// Content of sample.js
const {BigQuery} = require('@google-cloud/bigquery');
```

Normally, there should be no issue with requiring packages.
Anyhow, requiring the `bigquery` itself fails with this error:

> Error in includes/sample.js
> Failed to resolve stream

Investigating a little further shows that it is not a BQ-specific error. Some packages natively available in Node.js (e.g. `fs` or `child_process`) fail to import while packages like `date-and-time` installed using npm are requirable.

Thus, I assume that, like with other Google environments, BQs Dataform might have some environment pre-created messing with installations; anyhow, this is just an assumption. Also, according to the [BQ Dataform docs](https://cloud.google.com/dataform/docs/install-package) it actually should work.

**Question**

How can I successfully import packages installed via npm?
Also, I would be very interesting if anybody knew why the described steps fail even though they are according to the docs.

**Edit 27.03.23**

As side-note: Outside the Web-IDE the Node.js-project works fine and package-requiring does not pose any issue; thus, the issue should not be about a broken project but rather related to the Dataform instance in BigQuery.

Comment: Are you facing a  'module not found ' error also?

Comment: @kiranmathew No, as far as I progressed with my investigations it seems that the module got installed and is available but it lacks dependencies. I installed `stream` by adding it to the package.json manually and the error changed to the same issue with `emitter`. Also adding `emitter` to package.json (leaving aside that this is error-prone) could not resolve `Failed to resolve emittter'. So I assume that klicking `Install packages` in the BQ-frontend doesn't install everything. I also figured out that other packages run into the same issue, so it is not `@google-cloud/bigquery`-exclusive

Comment: Hi @Markus did the answer below solve your issue?

Comment: Hey @kiranmathew, unfortunately not. I think this will be a support-ticket - If I find something out I'll document it here :) Inbetween, any ideas are appreciated

Comment: Hi @Markus, if you have a support plan, you can open a new GCP [support case](https://cloud.google.com/support/). Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) describing your issue.

Answer (score 0):

When you create your first Dataform repository, Dataform automatically generates a service account. Dataform uses the service account to interact with BigQuery on your behalf.

Your Dataform service account ID is in the following format:

service-YOUR_PROJECT_NUMBER@gcp-sa-dataform.iam.gserviceaccount.com

Also grant the following permission to the above-mentioned service account:

- BigQuery Job User role.
- BigQuery Data Editor role.
- BigQuery Data Viewer role.

And talking about hierarchy take the .js file outside the include folder.

I hope your issue is resolved by this

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you cannot install emitter because the installation becomes too large and it times out.  According to google documentation there is a limit of 200MB. It would be nice to find a way to work around this problem in order to query tables within javascript in dataforma js files.